# Regex to split a dutch address

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to split a Dutch address but I'm kinda stuck.

The problem is that Dutch streets might have numbers in them.

```
$input_string = "name3 street 24a";

$address = "";
$number = "";
$addition = "";

$matches = array();
if(preg_match('/(?P<address>[^\d]+) (?P<number>\d+.?)/', $input_string, $matches)){
    $address = $matches['address'];
    $number = $matches['number'];
    if (preg_match('/(?P<nr>[^\d]+) (?P<addition>\d+.?)/', $number, $matches)) {
        $number = $matches['nr'];
        $addition = $matches['addition'];
    }
} else { // no number found, it is only address
    $address = $input_string;
}
echo $address . "\n";
echo $number. "\n";
echo $addition. "\n";
```

That wil ignore "name3".

I guess I am trying to strip off the last numbers and an optional letter.
Can anyone help me fix this?

Example inputs:

> name3 street 22a
>
> street 3
>
> street 3a
>
> dr. street 24a

Comment: You mean just find the last occurrence and replace with nothing [like this](https://regex101.com/r/jM2cA3/2)?

Answer (score 0):

> I guess I am trying to strip off the last numbers and an optional letter.

This can be accomplished by following regex.

**Regex:** `(?:\d+[a-z]*)$`

**Explanation:** It looks for a `number` followed by an optional `letter`.

**Replacement to do:** Replace with `nothing`.

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jM2cA3/3)